# CSS: replace font icons with text

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have a header where buttons are displayed as font icons. I want to replace them with simple text for each button. Here's my code right now, how would I go about doing that? I hope I'm getting this right

```
<li class="wp_dashboard_tab_content_header_%1$s">
    <a href="#tab_wp_dashboard_tab_content_header_%1$s"
      id="wp_dashboard_tab_content_header_%1$s" 
      class="wp_dashboard_icon_header_%1$s wp_dashboard_icon">
        <span></span>
    </a>
</li>
```

In my CSS file I have, for example

```
.wp_dashboard_icon_header_home:before {
  content: "\e653";
}
```

Comment: Did you try something? What particular problem do you have?

Comment: `content: "foobar";` ?

Comment: @VladimirSerykh Serykh I can't figure out exactly what I need to change and where, in order for the replacement to work. There are 4 buttons on my navbar, each of them is generated automatically as shown in the code above. I want to replace the icon displayed for each with just basic text. I tried this  <a href="#tab_wp_dashboard_tab_content_header_%1$s">Text</a> but I figured then all my buttons would be named Text, and they each need to keep their intended name.

Comment: @Vucko I'll try that, thanks. First time using StackOverflow, just getting the hang of this

Comment: Do you want to use jquery?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add to the specific element `font-family`. That's because by default, element who need to be render as font-icon has `font-family` which contains icon but no letters or numbers.

Try to set

```
.wp_dashboard_icon_header_home:before {
   font-family:Arial;
   content: "Some text";
}
```